# If there is a sorted list of integers, then if i use the inbuilt set function in Python to remove duplicates, it changed the order of elements. WHY?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, duplicates, set

I have a sorted list of integers. but I wanted to remove the duplicates so I used inbuilt set function expected that it would not change the positions but it just to remove duplicates.

it resulted me with changed positions of negative integers from the sorted list!

to remove the duplicates from the sorted list! I've tried inbuilt set to remove duplicates but ended up changed positions of negative integers

```py
lis=[0,-1,,-1,3,3,1,10]
lis.sort()
l=set(lis)
print(l)
```

the answer I expected is [-1,0,1,3] but the actual output was [0,1,3,-1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set is an unordered collection, so it will change the order.

> Being an unordered collection, sets do not record element position or order of insertion.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

To sort a list and remove duplicates try

```
l = sorted(set(lis))
```

Answer (score 0):

The set datatype is an unordered data structure whereas list is ordered. The order of elements will always change in a set. To remove duplicates from a list you can write a function and run the list through it. The following function should do it.

```
    def remove_duplicates(a):

            t = []
            for i in a:
                    if i not in t:
                    t.append(i)
            return t 
    lis=remove_duplicates(lis)
```